# Ubuntu 14 USB Installation - Help

Tags: usb

I'm installing Ubuntu 14 onto my old laptop from USB. The "Try Me" portion works, I'm navigating around files, editing, going online etc however when I try to install I'm hitting an error.

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 346649 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 346742 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

Left it running for about 3 hours and it just checks online something then repeats those errors.

I'm running a Toshiba Satellite that used to be Vista. It crashed and burned so I wiped that part of the drive then tried again. 
I'm using about 1700mB as swap space, drive 1 as actual installation mounting as `/` and drive 2 contains all my files. I'm installing from USB.

Comment: check the md5sum on the disk, it might be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the installation again by recreating the installation media. If that doesn't help then please re-download the .iso file. It may have happened that your installation file may contain an error.

If this doesn't solve your problem , please feel free to ask.